# my Drawables images are not showing as images in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have open my Android Project in eclipse today, in my resource folders the Drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi the images are corrupted like below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: its not corrupted dude you need to open as image not text editor

Comment: open with image editor

Comment: just open it in some image editor, or mspaint etc

Comment: how i can open in image? when i am double click on image it is open like the above mentioned in sanpshot.